# Merge 2 pyspark dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes

dataframe 1

```
Place    Month   People
IND      2021/07 1111
USA      2021/07 2222
RUS      2021/07 3333
```

dataframe 2

```
Place    Month   People  Capacity
AUS      2021/07 1111    4532
COL      2021/07 2222    2988
CAN      2021/07 3333    5323
```

I need to merge the 2 dataframes to get

```
Place    Month   People  Capacity
IND      2021/07 1111
USA      2021/07 2222
RUS      2021/07 3333
AUS      2021/07 1111    4532
COL      2021/07 2222    2988
CAN      2021/07 3333    5323
```

Im just getting the first dataframe with this code.
`df_result=df_1.union(df_2)`

Suggestions pls

Comment: what spark version you are using?

Comment: Maybe you want `unionAll` or `unionByName`?

Comment: You are trying to`union` two dataframes that do not have the same columns. I doubt it works. I'd add `df_1=df_1.withColumn('Capacity', F.lit(0))` and then try union.